# There are infinitely many odd numbers not expressible as the sum of a prime number and a power of $2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many odd integers that are not expressible as the sum of a prime number and a power of two.

This is a difficult problem. Please give me some hints and some examples of this.

Comment: Sum of consecutive prime numbers , or different prime numbers?

Comment: This looks very difficult. I may be wrong, but it isn't clear that this can be settled at all with methods of elementary-number-theory. Therefore I added the tag number-theory.

Comment: For example, there are approximately $n/\ln n$ primes smaller than a given odd integer $n$, and approximately $\log_2n$ powers of two  in the same range. Therefore there are $n\cdot\log_2n/\ln n=n/\ln 2>n$ pairs of odd primes and powers of two that could potentially be used. Thus there is some reason to think that a number needs to be unlucky not to be of the presecribed form. Asking for a hint may thus be misguided :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, the Erdos proof is quite elementary. Not easy, not obvious, but elementary.

Comment: I take your word for that @Gerry! So I was wrong. Not for the last time I'm afraid.

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it, @Jyrki, you can see for yourself by following the link in the answer I posted.

Comment: @Crostul What is the ambiguity ?

Comment: Closed as unclear? What is unclear about this question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Very clever. I concede your cleverness, but try taking small odd numbers and seeing if they can't be expressed of this form. You'll find most of them can.

Comment: @Gerry a power vote coming up... done. I may be abusing my mod powers. But at least I vary between unilateral closure and unilateral reopenings :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What is a power vote ?

Comment: @user230452: It is a vote that takes effect immediately. Comes with a moderator's diamond. Needs to be used sparingly and with caution. Something I may have failed ro remember on occasion.

Comment: Someone told me to correct myself and the question was different in the body and heading but didn't clarify what was different.

Comment: @user230452 It was something like "infinite many odd numbers which cannot be expressed by the sum of a power of $2$ and an odd number", if I remember right.

Comment: @Peter That is the question ! Unless you mean it should be infinitely and not infinite. I didn't edit the question so I don't think I wrote infinite instead

Comment: An odd number is obvioulsy the sum of a power of $2$ and an ODD NUMBER. The second "odd number" was replaced by "prime"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erdos proved this in the paper in which he introduced the concept of *covering congruences*. The reference is On integers of the form $2^n+ p$  and some related problems, Summa Brasil Math 11(1950), 1-11. The proof is given by Fabrykowski and Smotzer, Covering systems of congruences, Math Mag 78 (2005) 228-231, available at http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004416309960.pdf.bannered.pdf

EDIT. The Erdos paper is available at http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf. Some of it is heavy going, but the part that answers the question here is Theorem 3 and its proof, which is quite elementary. http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/ has the collected papers of Erdos.

Comment: Intuitively, I guessed this because the gap of the powers of $2$ eventually becomes very large, but I do not think I would be able to prove it.

Comment: Erdos was very clever.

Comment: Thanks for the reference ! How did you know which paper contained the solution just by seeing the question ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, Gerry. You're right - the solution is elementary. To Erdös at least :-)

Comment: I know something about covering congruences, and I know their history. And I know how to use Google.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Are you a professor ? Whenever I see your username, I remember the professor in Good Will Hunting.

Comment: I'm on the Math faculty at Macquarie University.

Comment: @Peter To compensate the gaps between powers of two, there are a lot of primes. I tried a counting argument the first thing I did (see my comments below the main post). But, there are enough pairs $(2^k,p)$ with both below $n$ to cover all $n/2$ choices. Of course, that does not invalidate your intuition.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wish I had some teacher like you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that was my second thought. But I had a feeling that the gaps eventually "win" and that someone has proven it.

Comment: Does the cited paper contain the proof or just a reference to a paper that contained the proof ?

Comment: @user230452: It contains the proof. It is easy to follow. Even I managed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What was the main idea ? Prime number theorem ? Bertrands postulate ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're a tenured professor ! I'm just a lowly undergrad who studies Math in all his spare time. Lol. I asked because there's a reference to a 11 page paper at the end, and I though this one is just a summary.

Comment: @Peter: I copied the key passage for readers' convenience.

Comment: Yes, finally I looked at the paper. Indeed not very complicated, but of course very clever.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There are some other problems of Erdos' I'd like to see. Should I post separate questions for all of them or is there a way I can ask you for references otherwise.  I did Google this problem but I didn't get any relevant hits.

Comment: @user230452: For the record. I'm not a tenured professor. I doubt I ever will as I have mostly  given up research and thus won't add to my list of merits. I am a tenured lecturer - a position with a lot less prestige, but also a lot less stress :-)

Answer (score 3):

Below is the key passage from the paper Gerry linked to.

If $k$ is a nonnegative integer, then at least one of the following congruences holds:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
2^k&\equiv1\pmod3,\\ 
2^k&\equiv1\pmod7,\\ 
2^k&\equiv2\pmod5,\\ 
2^k&\equiv8\pmod{17},\\ 
2^k&\equiv2^7\pmod{13},\\
2^k&\equiv2^{23}\pmod{241}.
\end{aligned}
$$
[JL:
This is easy to see by checking, case-by-case, that irrespective of the residue class of $k$ modulo $24$ at least one of the above congruences holds. Observe that $2$ is of order $12$ modulo $13$ and of order $24$ modulo $241$. The authors of that paper did it by first observing that the relevant residue classes modulo $2,3,4,8,12$ and $24$ cover all the integers.]

Now 
consider 
the 
congruences 
$1\pmod3$, 
$1 
\pmod 
7$, 
$2 
\pmod 
5$, 
$8 
\pmod 
{17}$, 
$2^7 
\pmod 
{13}$, 
and 
$2^{23} 
\pmod 
{241}$. 
Since 
the 
moduli 
are 
pairwise 
relatively 
prime, 
there 
are 
infinitely 
many 
integers 
that 
satisfy 
all 
the 
congruences, 
by 
virtue 
of 
the 
Chinese 
Remainder 
Theorem. 
Now, 
if 
an 
odd 
integer 
$a$ 
satisfies 
all 
the 
congruences, 
then 
all 
the 
integers 
of 
the 
form 
$a-2^k$
are 
divisible 
by 
one 
of 
the 
moduli 
$3, 
7, 
5, 
17, 
13 $
or 
$241.$ 
It 
follows 
that 
$a-2^k$
is 
not 
prime 
and 
therefore 
$a$ 
does 
not 
have 
the 
form 
$a=2^k+p$.

Comment: This is pretty brilliant.

Comment: Can I ask what the smallest such number will be ?

Comment: Also, is there anything special about the moduli chosen ?

Comment: Erdös was a smart dude.

Comment: One little thing : $a$ must be chosen large enough, but this is no problem since infinite many $a$ satisfy the congruences. But it still not quite obvious why one of the congruences must be satisfied. Please add some details. Do I only need to consider $k$ mod 24 ?

Comment: I'm confused about whether I should accept this answer now.

Comment: No. Don't accept this. I posted it only to back up Gerry's claim that the proof is elementary.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why is this answer under community wiki instead of your name ?

Comment: @user230452: I placed it under CW as in *Credit waived* (a term originally coined by Henning Makholm). Here Erdös and Gerry Myerson did all the work, I just copy pasted and added a bit of TeX.

Comment: Erdos's argument is brilliant.  But I'm confused by the last step.  Yes,  $a-2^k$ is divisible by one of the primes 3, 5,7, 13,17, or 241, but could it happen that $a-2^k$ is one of those primes, so that $a=2^k+p$, with $p=3, 5, 7, 13, 17,$ or $241$?  Apparently not, but no one comments about this, and I don't see the (probably) trivial reason why this can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many related results to this problem about expressing integers as the sum of some number of primes and sum number of powers of two.

This problem was originally a conjecture of de Polignac that every sufficiently large odd integer may be expressed as $p + 2^v$. Romanoff showed that a positive proportion of the odd integers may be expressed as such, however van der Corput showed that the exceptions formed a set of positive density (!). Finally, Erdos exhibited an arithmetic progression which are all exceptions, as shown in the top answer.

As for similar conjectures, Gallagher proved that the density of odd integers which may be written as

$$p + 2^{\nu_1} + \dots + 2^{\nu_r}$$

for $r \leq k$ tends to $1$ as $k \to \infty$. This result is quite old and am not sure what progress there has been since.